# Read and write to log file

Tags: vb.net, streamreader

I have a program with a few parallel processes writing to a log file, tha main program is also reading the log and pooling it to a text field.

The thing is, reached a certain point, I miss the log and always read 0 bytes, though the processes keep writing it. This is my reader sub, where after some time, the line *Dim n As Integer = stream.Read(bytes, numBytesRead, numBytesToRead)* always gives 0:

```
Public Function readFile(ByRef stream As FileStream) As String
    Dim bytes() As Byte = New Byte((stream.Length) - 1) {}
    Dim numBytesToRead As Integer = CType(stream.Length, Integer)

    Dim numBytesRead As Integer = 0
    While (numBytesToRead > 0)
        ' Read may return anything from 0 to numBytesToRead. 
        Dim n As Integer = stream.Read(bytes, numBytesRead, numBytesToRead)
        ' Break when the end of the file is reached. 
        If (n = 0) Then
            Exit While
        End If
        numBytesRead = (numBytesRead + n)
        numBytesToRead = (numBytesToRead - n)

    End While
    numBytesToRead = bytes.Length

    Return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes)
End Function
```

The *stream* parameter is a global variable (global to the main Winform) declared as:

```
Private FSReaderLog As FileStream
```

And initialized (only in form load) as shown next, opening stream and trunking file content:

```
Public Function InitLog(ByVal ruta_fichero As String) As FileStream
    Dim FS As New FileStream(ruta_fichero, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.ReadWrite)
    FS.SetLength(0)
    FS.Flush()
    Return FS
End Function
```

What can be wrong in the reader?

Thank you

Comment: Try to use SyncLock to lock the sream when you read or write http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3a86s51t.aspx

Comment: Thank you, do you think it's necesary also when reading? There are actually 2 programs reading the log (mine and logview4net)...

Comment: I don't know. It was only a suggestion that you should see if it solves your problem. 2 programs are not a problem since you're specifing the currect file share, but a single stream need to be locked between threads.

Comment: I agree.  If you are going to use the same stream, you should lock on it when you use it.  You could, however, create a separate thread for reading, or even a new thread each time you read or write to it.